# Почему $(window).load выполняется раньше, чем $(document).ready?

Tags: javascript, кэширование

По идеи такого не должно быть, но судя по `console.log()` при повторных обращений к странице время от времени `$(window).load` выполняется раньше, чем завершится выполнение `$(document).ready`. Что это? Из-за кеширования страницы?

UPD: `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />` не помогает, поэтому дело не в кеше

UPD2: при перезагрузки страницы всегда все начинает корректно отрабатывать

Comment: Я уже [поверял](//stackoverflow.com/a/42341458/4928642), что так не бывает кроме одного случая - когда подписка делается из самого обработчика. Так что стоит предоставить [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Событие `DOMContentLoaded`, которое "вызывает" метод `ready()` у `document` происходит всегда раньше исходя из документации: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Поэтому нужен ваш пример.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  console.log("window");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("document");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Код достаточно громоздкий и напичкан большим количеством ajax-запросов. Я не уверен, что при копировании проблема может сохранится. Думаю, что кто либо сталкивался с подобным поведением и может подсказать из опыта. Например, у меня в скрипте много конструкций windows.load и document.ready. Могло ли это как-то повлиять на порядк выполнения?

Comment: @КонстантинКузнецов а что означает upd2 "после перезагрузки страницы"?

Answer (score 2):

### `$(window).load`

> Событие [load](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_load) происходит, когда сам элемент и все его дочерние
>   элементы полностью загружены. Это событие может происходить на
>   элементах, которые обладают полями URL (объект window, картинки,
>   скрипты, фреймы).
>
> **Замечание 1**: в некоторых случаях, если картинка содержится в кеше браузера, событие load может не произойти. Для такого случая можно
>   воспользоваться специальным событием `event.special.load`, которое
>   определено в небольшом плагине.
>
> **Замечание 2**: если вам не требуется готовность мультимедийных файлов, лучше воспользоваться методом `.ready()`, который устанавливает
>   обработчик готовности структуры документа, что происходит раньше
>   начала загрузки файлов мультимедиа.

Тут все предельно ясно, если пишем `$(window).load` то код, написанный внутри этой конструкции, начнёт работу **когда будет готов весь DOM включая изображения**. Такой вызов логичнее производить в случае, когда необходимо работать с изображениями (расчёт размеров изображения или еще что-то).

---

### `$(document).ready`

`$(document).ready` код внутри блока начнёт выполняться сразу после того, **когда будет готов DOM, за исключением картинок**. Указанный код будет выполняться непосредственно после готовности DOM, не дожидаясь полной загрузки изображений. Вызов `$(document).ready` несколько раз приведет к последовательному исполнению вызовов друг за другом, в последовательности сверху вниз.

---

### `$(window).load` или `$(document).ready`?

Хотя, для воспроизведения такой ситуации потребуется немало усилий, все равно остаются нюансы. Иногда, такое возникает, когда внутри события `ready` срабатывает подписка на `load` к примеру, или наоборот, что приводит к странному поведению.

Если опираться на некоторые другие ответы, такие как:

- [After all $(document).ready() have run, is there an event for that?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008807/5275890)
- [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698214/5275890)
- [multiple $(document).ready and $(window).load in $(document).ready](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42341458/5275890)

то приходишь к выводу, что событие `$(window).load` всегда должно произойти после `$(document).ready`. Но, факт присутствия такого поведения имеется.

Теперь подумаем про кеширование страницы. Да, действительно, после того, как изображения будут закэшированы весь написанный вами код, скорее всего, начнет выполняться последовательно, сверху вниз. Таким образом получатся ситуации, когда `$(window).load` и `$(document).ready` оба этих блока будут ждать только загрузку `DOM`, а если еще и подписка на событие внутри события будет, то  получится коллизия, и стоящий `$(window).load` перед `$(document).ready` выполнится раньше. В любом случае, коллизия происходит не просто так и нужно заняться исправлением кода и его рефакторингом.

Полезные ссылки для ознакомления:

- [`$(document).ready` vs `$(window).load` vs `window.onload`](http://front-end.su/2016/02/12/load-events/)
- [Обработчик события load `.load()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_load)
- [Обработчик готовности дерева DOM `.ready()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0_DOM)
- [`.ready()`](https://jquery-docs.ru/ready/)
- [`.load()`](https://jquery-docs.ru/load-event/)
- [Справочник jQuery Загрузка документа](https://jquery-docs.ru/category/events/document-loading/)

Comment: _"таким образом получатся ситуации, когда стоящий $(window).load перед $(document).ready выполнится раньше"_ - [это утверждение сомнительно](//stackoverflow.com/a/42341458/4928642).

Comment: @Qwertiy, когда `load` и `ready` ждут одного и того же - только загрузки DOM, и таких блоков идущих подряд несколько - тогда они будут выполнены последовательно и в этом случае получится, что выполнится  `load` перед следующим `ready`. Если бы были только  `ready` - все бы выполнялось нормально, тут  `load` с кэшированием вносит коллизии.

Comment: Можно пример (или хотя бы подробное описание), как воспроизвести?

Comment: @Qwertiy, воспроизвести...нужна куча кода, с несколькими `load` и `ready`, причем на странице должны быть ресурсы, типа картинок, чтобы они подгружались. Похожее видел, в одном проекте, помогло объединение блоков. Такой код, идущие в перемешку `load` и `ready` не в единственных экземплярах до добра не доведет - это факт. В сниппете такое вряд ли воспроизведешь :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, кстати, такое наверное вряд ли удастся сделать, только если из обработчика не происходит подписки...а так да, после `ready` должен быть `load`...но я помню, что было такое, что все шло не так, как хотелось бы. Без кода автора вряд ли получится воспроизвести.

Comment: у меня `ready` и `load` много, так как у меня сборщик собирает все куски (у каждого свой `ready` и `load) из рабочего проекта и создает один склеенных файл .min.js  Не хочу объединять блоки, так как это затруднит поддержку проекта, либо поищу плагин для gulp, либо буду экспериментировать по-странке: код кусками удалять и проверять, когда заработает, а потом выискивать зависимость.. Результат отпишу. Если есть у кого еще идеи - предлагайте).

Comment: @КонстантинКузнецов, предложенный вариант с частичным разбором кода (удаление кусками) поможет. Я вам так и предлагал в ответе: *нужно заняться исправлением кода и его рефакторингом* :) отпишите, интересно, что не так у вас

Comment: Проблему решил убрав ajax-запрос, который создавал картинку и выполнялся 10 сек.

@denis-bubnov Вот что происходило: Ajax отправив запрос и не получив ответ по какой-то причине считал, что DOM-построен и пора вызвать событие load, а через 10 сек прилетал ответ от, казалось бы, уже мертвого запроса, поэтому ready довыполнялся позже load =)

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready` - Срабатывает когда браузер загрузил `html` и построил `DOM дерево`, а `$(window).load` - срабатывает когда еще и загружены все ресурсы (картинки и прочее), то есть теоретически `$(document).ready` срабатывает раньше, но после перезагрузки страницы ресурсы (картинки) ку  нас могут быть закешированы, в таком случае `$(window).load` может начать выполнятся примерно совместно с `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Совместно? Js однопоточный. А ещё, картинок и ресурсов может вообще не быть - но это же не влияет на порядок.

Comment: "примерно совместно" тут имел ввиду, что события сработают примерно совместно и код который был выше сработает раньше.

Answer (score 1):

Внимательно посмотрел Network в DevTools и проблему решил убрав ajax-запрос, который создавал картинку и выполнялся 10 сек.

**Вот что происходило:** Ajax отправив запрос и не получив ответ по какой-то причине считал, что DOM-построен и пора вызвать событие load, а через 10 сек прилетал ответ от, казалось бы, уже мертвого запроса, поэтому ready довыполнялся позже load =)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего подписка на возникающее позже событие делается уже из другого обработчика события `load`. [Других способов воспроизвести такую ситуацию мне неизвестно.](//stackoverflow.com/a/42341458/4928642)