# Можно ли вкладывать $(window).on("load") внутрь $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть [слайдер](http://mhelper.ru/slider1/). На мобильном телефоне слайдер работает корректно только при первом открытии страницы. При обновлении страницы слайдер не работает.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* другие скрипты */
    $(window).on("load", function(){
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            autoHeight: true,
            smartSpeed: 300,
            mouseDrag: false,
            pullDrag: false,
            nav: true,
            navText: ""
        });
    });
});
```

Если `$(window).on("load")` вынести за `$(document).ready()`, то все работает и при обновлении страницы. Почему так может происходить?

Comment: [Вот тут нашел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664645/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-window-load-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-document-ready)